# OAuth2 user token best practice

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using the "Code Grant Flow" in order to obtain the token server-side passing the secret. Now I need to send the token from the server to the client, to be able to make AJAX request with the bearer token in the header.
Which is the most safe way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the implicit grant flow?

Comment: Because the implicit grant flow returns a client token instead of a bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

Any method will do as long as you return it over a secure **`HTTPs`** channel. 
It would be an application specific call, running between the frontend and backend of a single application, probably based on a session cookie that maintains state between the two of them.

Comment: I agree with you that HTTPS ensure me safty during the trip. But once the token is arrived on the client it must be stored somewere to be available when the client needs to use it. If I use a cookie or I embed the token in the page it's not so difficult to find it in the temporary internet files and be used by "others".